# Provider .read() vs .watch()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

I just updated my `flutter_bloc` library to `6.1.1` in which states:

> bloc' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use context.read or context.watch instead. Will be removed in v7.0.0.
> Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Here is a part of code that I did have to change:

```
class ContractSubscriptionForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final ContractSubscription contractSubscription;
  const ContractSubscriptionForm(this.contractSubscription, {Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ContractSubscriptionFormBloc(
        contractSubscription,
        context.read<CoursesGroupBloc>().state.coursesGroupList,  // <---change to .read()
      ),
      child: SubscriptionFormBody(),
    );
  }
}
```

The part I did change is this: `context.bloc<CoursesGroupBloc>().state.coursesGroupList,` to `context.read<CoursesGroupBloc>().state.coursesGroupList,` and is now working.

In the documentation for the `.read()` function I read the following:

> This method is the opposite of [watch].
> It will not make widget rebuild when the value changes and cannot be called inside [StatelessWidget.build]/[State.build].
> On the other hand, it can be freely called outside of these methods.

For some reason, this makes no sense, since the upper code is within a `build` of a StatelessWidget and is working with the `.read()` function but not with the `.watch()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you didn't call context.read inside the StatelessWidget's build, you did that inside BlocProvider during creating ContractSubscriptionFormBloc.
if you try to do the following:

```
class example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<CoursesGroupBloc>().state.coursesGroupList;
    //the rest of your code
  }
}
```

this error will appear:
Tried to use `context.read<bloc>` inside either a `build` method or the `update` callback of a provider

Answer (score -1):

some times in provider the .read() is used to variables and .watch()is used to function.

Comment: Not really. You can also use .read for functions.